# CommandBar XAML - UWP - Properties Anniversary Edition SDK

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml, commandbar

In my app, I have many commandsBar, but with this last SDK, the button "..." disappear on my commandBar.

I search on web and the conclusion: At Build 2016, showed changes in many XAML elements. CommandBars specific, have new properties.

If I put "OverflowButtonVisibility="Visible"" on my commnadBar, "..." appear correctly, but, is not working with Min Target Version 10586. Only work with Min Target Version Windows 10 Anniversary Edition  (10.0; Build 14393).

My question are: I need to show always "...", How do this?

Min Version Supported: 10240

Max Version Supported: Windows 10 Anniversary Edition  (10.0; Build 14393).

MyCode:

```
<CommandBar x:Name="CommandBar">
        <AppBarButton Icon="Filter" Label="Filter X" Style="{StaticResource StyleFilter}">
        </AppBarButton>
    </CommandBar>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it not showing if you just let the OverflowButtonVisibility unset? I got it unset and the "..." shows everytime...

Comment: You may also think of publishing two packages one for each version.

Comment: Hi People, I dont know the problem, but if I remove the style, it's work perfectly.

I try to create a new style on Blend, and the problem are solved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can handle this in all versions is to Template your own `CommandBar`. Create a new TemplatedControl, base it off `CommandBar` and copy the `CommandBar`'s style from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299118.aspx). Then inside the templated control you can add your own version of `OverflowButtonVisibility="Visible"` by creating your own `DependencyProperty` which can then be bound to or a default of `Visible` can be set.

You'll then need to replace all of your current `CommandBar`'s with your TemplatedControl.